# android - changing the system settings of a rooted device from inside the app

Tags: android, root

I am trying to change the sms limit described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663514/android-sending-lots-of-sms-messages/2434308#2434308) from inside the app. The app is assumed to be running on a rooted device. I'm using the [RootTools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/downloads/detail?name=RootTools-1.1.0-sdk3-generic.jar&can=2&q=) to check if the device is rooted or not. I'm trying to figure out how to write the actual setting on to the `settings.db`. Any suggestion which could help me in this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If settingd.db is sqlite db file then you can open this file with any sqlite tools and manually modify it.

Comment: I want to do it from inside the app itself.

Comment: what happen if you access "/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db" this path to modify data in database helper class?

Comment: ok, I cant see your link, can you post your error here?

Comment: t returns an error. You can check the `openDatabase` method [here][1] for more details

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: still not getting your error.

Comment: It is something(or may be exactly) like this 
`SQLiteException : Database Cannot be opened`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this solved by doing this:

- copy the `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db` to my application folder `/data/data/my_app_directory/`.
- update the table in the database using the `SQLiteDatabase` class.
- copy back the database from `/data/data/my_app_directory/settings.db` to `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/`

The copy operations were done by using `RootTools.sendShell`

Comment: nice. now is there any problem?

Comment: isn´t it possible to operate directly on the original settings.db?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible.

Comment: I made it possible. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this if you have root access. Its a lengthy process but you can do this :

**Step 1:** copy `settings.db` from `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/` using `RootBrowser` from the device and than change the value using `sqliteBrowser` which you want to update than update settings.db and put in `assets` package of your project

**Step 2:** Copy this file into your application folder (anywhere where you can access) using `asset manager` for that you need

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

this function will copy file from assets

```
public static void copyAssets(Context context, String assetPath, String outFilename) {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open(assetPath);
            File outFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), outFilename);
              
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to copy asset: " + outFilename, e);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

**Step 3:** overwrite the system `settings.db` file system path (destPath) is `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/`

```
public static void copyToSystem(final String sourceFilePath, final String destPath) {
        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
//                    
                    os.writeBytes("cp -f " + sourceFilePath + " " + destPath + "\n");
                    os.flush();
                    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                    os.flush();
                    process.waitFor();
                    process.waitFor();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        background.start();
    }
```

**Step 4:** Reboot device

That's all done.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you don't need to copy settings.db, you can update it with RootTools like

```
CommandCapture commandLogcat = new CommandCapture(0, "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db \"UPDATE secure SET value = '192.168.2.140' WHERE name = 'eth_ip';\"");
RootTools.getShell(true).add(commandLogcat).getExitCode();
```