# Wifi Optimization

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-settings

Anyone know of any way to enable/disable wifi optimization programmaticaly via code, or to at least check if it is enbaled (so to prompt the user)? When this is enabled and the device goes to sleep (despite wake and wifi locks) wifi communication with a third-party device stops.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Device must be rooted to use this method. Your app does *not* need to be a system app as we can grant ourselves temporary system app like access.  This works in API 21 / 4.*, not sure what else.

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>` to AndroidManifest.xml

The internet may tell you that your app must be a system app, but you can ignore that because this method gets around that problem at least in this situation.

Use this code (simplified for this post).

```
// Grant your app temporary system level like settings access awesomeness
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su pm grant <yourpackagename> android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS");
// Read the value first to see if you need to set it at all
int curVal = android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(),"wifi_suspend_optimizations_enabled",2);
switch( curVal ) {
  case 0:
    // already disabled
    break;
  case 1:
    // attempt to disable!
    boolean success = android.provider.Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(),"wifi_suspend_optimizations_enabled",0);
    if( success ) {
      // yay worked! maybe check it again to be sure
    }
    else {
      // failed to put
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    // Failed to read value, access not granted
    break;
}
```

I derived a lot of this from:
http://muzso.hu/2013/04/07/changing-android-system-settings-eg.-airplane-mode-radios-via-commandline-on-rooted-phone

The method described in this answer can also be used to change other protected system settings, but it may be difficult to track down the exact name of the setting to change. 
Useful information is available at [android-changing-the-system-settings-of-a-rooted-device-from-inside-the-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392067/android-changing-the-system-settings-of-a-rooted-device-from-inside-the-app) namely that you can open `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/setting‌​s.db` in a sqlite editor of your choice to look up the table and key names of the setting you want to change.
`wifi_suspend_optimizations_enabled` is in the Global table, but that is not the only table available.
Other settings than wifi optimization may require `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>`

This information may not apply to all devices or situation.

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is NO way to check Wifi Optimization option programmatically.

check classes about wifi APIs.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Via ADB shell (assuming root access):

```
settings set global wifi_suspend_optimizations_enabled 0
```

You can verify if this is successful by observing logcat when turning screen off and on:

```
logcat -v time | grep -e wpa | grep SETSUSPENDMODE
```

If you see this value being toggled during screen off & on events then Wifi Optimizations are enabled and are creating the issue you're seeing. Once disabled this behavior should stop.